# 3D video on normal LCD monitor

Tags: windows, lcd, 3d, 3d-multimedia

Can I play 3d video on normal LCD Monitor and see it with 3d (red & blue) glass, or do I need a special type of monitor (3d enabled)? If so is there any software that can be used to view 3D video on normal LCD monitor?

Comment: ["Anaglyph"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With red and blue glasses, **yes - and you don't need any special software**.
If you just want to test your glasses, YouTube has a number of red-blue clips to start with. Search for "anaglyph".

EDIT: Unless you want to convert 3d video from different formats to red-blue.

With flickering glasses, you'll need at least a monitor that supports 100-120 Hz refresh rate to view comfortably.

With polarizing glasses, you need a polarization-capable monitor/tv.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, So if I Have simple red & blue 3D glass (http://www.ebay.com/itm/140598866556?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649#ht_3924wt_1039). I can see Anaglyph 3D video on normal CRT Monitor?

Comment: Yes. Both on LCD and CRT. Note that there are "red & blue" and "red & green" anaglyphs, but this could usually be corrected with monitor color tweaking

Comment: I tried watching a 3D video using red/blue glass, I can see some 3d effect but colors are not correct, (I see some bright green color only). May by something is wrong with my eyes.